# What's the difference between the Canon PowerShot S100 and the PowerShot SX260 HS?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, compact-cameras, powershot

I rather like the Canon PowerShot S100, it has received great reviews.

But I now see that the PowerShot SX260 HS has been launched at a similar price and wondered what the difference is.

The onsite comparator shows the SX260 as having greater zoom, but the S100 has the in-lens multi-function dial, the S100 also has lower f settings.

The differences seem to be less of this, more of that etc. I'm wondering if there is some profound difference and if the SX260 is meant to supersede the S100 or instead address another kind of user?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be basically deciding on image quality versus zoom capability.

The S100 has a bigger sensor, handles higher ISOs better and offers a faster lens. On the other hand, the SX260 offers you a lot more optical zoom.

There is no clear winner here, it all depends on what aspect you value the most in your shots. The ability to zoom further or the ability to register the shot with higher quality.

Note that none of these aspects would necessarily imply better pictures per se.

Comment: +1 The answer I was looking for, covers everything succinctly. Thanks.